# DynamoDB sends multiple update event and my lambda is called multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I've got a DynamoDB in AWS and it has a trigger on it with an AWS Lambda connected.
I need to send an email when a status reaches a particular value and it's done checking the `EventName=="MODIFY"` and the `newImage["Status"]` value.
What currently happens is that the event is fired 3 times and so 3 emails are sent...
I thought to set a value on DynamoDB telling that I've already sent an email, but doing so another trigger is fired and I don't know if the time between events is enough to perform this update... anyone has got this issue before? how did you handle it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you check the condition `EventName=="MODIFY"` in your function?

Comment: yes I do... but 3 times I receive MODIFY as event... I don't know if it's due to the fact I update 3 fields in another lambda, but I thought ti would have been sent only once

Comment: Can't you just compare the status field in the new and old image and only send the event when there is a difference? That way you would only send the notification when the status field changed.